# Unable to Access Hyperion Workspace in web App

Tags: oracle, hyperion, essbase

I have installed **Hyperion EPM** in **Oracle Linux 6.10**.
Database used is Oracle db 11gR2.

Foundation services, Essbase and planning are installed and configured successfully.

I run **start.sh** script to start all the EPM services.
But still **can not access workspace and hence any other EPM services form web app** since all the applications have been deployed to a single managed server.

The url that i am trying is: http://server-name:19000/workspace

I run **validate.sh** script and the screenshots of the results have been attached

[Foundation-Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpqXS.png)
[Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUsgv.png)

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the validation report output, it looks EPM is not starting at all.

If the issue is still open, please ensure Database is running before you start EPM.

Then, I would suggest you check if EPM processes are actually running, for what you can execute:

```
ps aux | grep oracle
```

To check if the processes started, or how far they went, you can check the starter logs:

```
EPM_ORACLE_INSTANCE/diagnostics/logs/starter
```

If until this point, processes are running, and starter logs looks OK, you can always try what the report itself suggest, check the validation logs in:

```
EPM_ORACLE_INSTANCE/diagnostics/logs/validation/
```